# using a text file for visitor counters / what happens when different requests updating one file ?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a simple visitor counters in y website using db

pleas ignore the syntax errors

```
    $date = date('Y/m/d');
        $record = $this->db->query("select * from `page_view` where `date` = '$date' ");

        if (empty($record))
            $this->db->query(" insert into `page_view`(`date`,`view` ) value ('$date' ,'1') ");
        else {
            $sql = "UPDATE `page_view` SET `view` = `view`+1 WHERE  `date` = '{$date}'";
            $this->db->query($sql);
            }
```

i'm having about 500k visitors per day which is a bit high and so is my mysql load .
i was wondering if i could use a text file to store each day hits and at the end of the day i would move/store the total visit count from text file to database .

at least until i identify and rewrite slow queries .

```
$today = date('Y/m/d');
list ($counter , $date ) = explode('#' , file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
$counter++;
if( $today == $data )
file_put_contents('counter.txt' , $counter.'#'.$date );
else
file_put_contents('counter.txt' , '1#'.$today);
```

is there any reason i shouldn't do this ?i'm i going to have any problem ?
and what would happen when couple of visitors want to update this file at the same time  ?

Comment: _"and what would happen when couple of visitors want to update this file at the same time?"_ --> that's why you use a database, not a text file. 500k `UPDATE` queries updating a simple DB counter should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third argument to file_put_contents() could be passed, "LOCK_EX", to "Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing."  I agree with @jszobody, though, a database would be the way to go.

http://php.net/file_put_contents

```
int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, **int $flags = 0** [, resource $context ]] )

LOCK_EX  Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing.
```

Comment: thanx , so other users will wait till the writing is done ? wouldn't this slow down loading time of my webpages ?

Comment: @max Precisely, which again suggests you should probably use a database instead.  You could combat the delay by putting your file_put_contents() in a standalone script and calling it using an asynchronous Javascript function.  The visitor wouldn't care if his background Javascript XHR call took .01ms, .02ms, or .5ms, etc, but the PHP LOCK_EX would properly record all visits.

Answer (score -2):

I believe php only handles one request at the time so updating the file should not be a problem, but why don't you just use analytics or any other. saves you some load and gives you a lot of info

Comment: PHP will not handle it atomically so there is a risk of two users reading the file contents (almost) simultaneously, both incrementing, and both writing (last one to write wins).